# 3D element rotation with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have designed a snowfall for a part of my site. The script code I wrote is not very professional but it does what I want.

I want each element (snow crystal) to have a 3D rotation as it descends and also not move in only one direction.

By not moving in one direction, I mean that if the element goes down to the left, it changes direction in the middle of the way and moves to the right to reach the bottom.

The codes that I have written so far are as follows:

```js
// 
// 
//
// *** 1 ***
// 
// 
// 

$(function () {
    var item_width = $('#slides div.a-2').outerWidth(true);
    var old_left = parseInt($('#slides div.a-1').css('left'));
    var old_right = parseInt($('#slides div.a-1').css('right'));
    var top_indent = old_left - item_width - old_right;
    var right_indent = item_width + old_left;
    var left = 0;
    var right = 0;

    var animateBox = function () {
        left = (left) ? 0 : (right_indent / 2);

        $('#slides div.a-1').animate({
            'bottom': top_indent + -150,
            'left': left,
            'right': right,
        }, 3200, function () {
            $('#slides div.a-1').css({ 'bottom': 50 });
            setTimeout(function () { animateBox(); }, 0);
        });
    }
    animateBox();
});


//
//
//
// *** 2 ***
//
//
//

$(function () {
    var item_width = $('#slides div.b-2').outerWidth(true);
    var old_left = parseInt($('#slides div.b-1').css('left'));
    var old_right = parseInt($('#slides div.b-1').css('right'));
    var top_indent = old_left - item_width - old_right;
    var right_indent = item_width + old_left;
    var left = 0;
    var right = 0;

    var animateBox = function () {
        left = (left) ? 0 : (right_indent / 2);

        $('#slides div.b-1').animate({
            'bottom': top_indent + -150,
            'left': right,
            'right': left
        }, 3200, function () {
            $('#slides div.b-1').css({ 'bottom': 50 });
            setTimeout(function () { animateBox(); }, 0);
        });
    }
    animateBox();
});

//
//
//
// *** 3 ***
//
//
//
$(function () {
    var item_width = $('#slides div.c-2').outerWidth(true);
    var old_left = parseInt($('#slides div.c-1').css('left'));
    var old_right = parseInt($('#slides div.c-1').css('right'));
    var top_indent = old_left - item_width - old_right;
    var right_indent = item_width + old_left;
    var left = 0;
    var right = 0;

    var animateBox = function () {
        left = (left) ? 0 : (right_indent / 2);

        $('#slides div.c-1').animate({
            'bottom': top_indent + -150,
            'left': left,
            'right': right
        }, 3200, function () {
            $('#slides div.c-1').css({ 'bottom': 50 });
            setTimeout(function () { animateBox(); }, 0);
        });
    }
    animateBox();
});
```

```css
body {
    direction: ltr;
}

.card_main {
    margin: 15px;
    padding: 10px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.card_body,
#slides {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden !important;
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 4px #000;
    background: #fff;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.content svg {
    fill: #003ced99;
    width: 75px;
    height: 45px;
}

.content1 {
    left: 50;
}

.content2 {
    left: 120px;
}

.content3 {
    left: 180px;
}

.direction_rtl {
    direction: rtl;
}

.direction_ltr {
    direction: ltr;
}

#slides div.a-1,
#slides div.a-2,
#slides div.b-1,
#slides div.b-2,
#slides div.c-1,
#slides div.c-2 {
    position: relative;
    list-style-type: none;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="card_main">

        <div class="card_body">

            <div id="slides">

                <div class="direction_ltr">
                    <div class="a-1">
                        <div class="a-2">
                            <div class="content content1">
                                <svg class="cardpro-iconBack_Common cardpro-iconback6" fill="#000" height="20px"
                                    width="20px" version="1.1" id="_x32_" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                                    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 512 512"
                                    xml:space="preserve">

                                    <g>
                                        <path
                                            d="M422.804,332.819c-34.87-7.132-11.07-25.884,15.846-33.085c26.899-7.201,16.591-45.641-11.708-35.981
                                   c-28.308,9.634-56.711,41.967-71.333,33.514c-11.69-6.746-31.178-17.982-38.502-22.217c1.881-6.02,2.888-12.425,2.888-19.049
                                   c0-6.624-1.006-13.029-2.888-19.041c7.324-4.226,26.811-15.48,38.502-22.226c14.622-8.435,43.025,23.888,71.333,33.531
                                   c28.298,9.643,38.606-28.798,11.708-35.999c-26.916-7.202-50.717-25.936-15.846-33.086c34.861-7.114,66.187-31.65,54.899-51.18
                                   c-11.288-19.531-48.17-4.673-71.797,21.955c-23.582,26.618-27.913-3.369-20.712-30.267c7.202-26.908-31.212-37.189-37.014-7.858
                                   c-5.819,29.332,7.98,70.116-6.633,78.543c-11.717,6.764-31.212,18.018-38.528,22.244c-8.637-9.38-20.056-16.145-32.954-19.05
                                   c0-8.435,0-30.959,0-44.469c0-16.871,42.186-25.315,64.709-45.004c22.497-19.688-5.626-47.828-25.332-28.141
                                   c-19.697,19.706-47.812,30.95-36.559-2.817C284.128,39.385,278.554,0,255.987,0c-22.55,0-28.132,39.385-16.88,73.135
                                   c11.253,33.767-16.862,22.523-36.55,2.817c-19.706-19.688-47.83,8.453-25.332,28.141c22.515,19.689,64.708,28.133,64.708,45.004
                                   c0,13.51,0,36.034,0,44.469c-12.898,2.905-24.326,9.669-32.954,19.05c-7.315-4.226-26.811-15.48-38.528-22.244
                                   c-14.613-8.426-0.84-49.211-6.632-78.543c-5.802-29.331-44.225-19.05-37.014,7.858c7.193,26.898,2.896,56.886-20.712,30.267
                                   C82.468,123.327,45.585,108.469,34.297,128c-11.288,19.531,20.038,44.067,54.899,51.18c34.853,7.15,11.052,25.884-15.855,33.086
                                   c-26.881,7.201-16.591,45.642,11.708,35.999c28.308-9.643,56.72-41.966,71.333-33.531c11.7,6.746,31.186,18,38.493,22.226
                                   c-1.873,6.012-2.87,12.416-2.87,19.041c0,6.624,0.997,13.029,2.87,19.049c-7.306,4.236-26.793,15.471-38.493,22.217
                                   c-14.613,8.453-43.026-23.879-71.333-33.514c-28.299-9.66-38.589,28.78-11.708,35.981c26.907,7.202,50.725,25.954,15.855,33.085
                                   c-34.861,7.115-66.188,31.65-54.899,51.181c11.288,19.54,48.171,4.673,71.797-21.955c23.608-26.618,27.904,3.369,20.712,30.268
                                   c-7.21,26.907,31.213,37.188,37.014,7.858c5.792-29.323-7.981-70.091,6.632-78.543c11.717-6.764,31.213-18.018,38.528-22.235
                                   c8.628,9.38,20.056,16.136,32.954,19.041c0,8.435,0,30.959,0,44.469c0,16.87-42.194,25.315-64.708,45.003
                                   c-22.498,19.689,5.626,47.83,25.332,28.141c19.688-19.706,47.803-30.95,36.55,2.818c-11.253,33.758-5.67,73.135,16.88,73.135
                                   c22.567,0,28.141-39.377,16.897-73.135c-11.253-33.768,16.862-22.524,36.559-2.818c19.706,19.688,47.829-8.452,25.332-28.141
                                   c-22.523-19.688-64.709-28.133-64.709-45.003c0-13.51,0-36.034,0-44.469c12.898-2.905,24.317-9.66,32.954-19.041
                                   c7.315,4.218,26.811,15.471,38.528,22.235c14.613,8.452,0.814,49.22,6.633,78.543c5.802,29.331,44.215,19.05,37.014-7.858
                                   c-7.201-26.899-2.896-56.886,20.712-30.268c23.627,26.628,60.509,41.494,71.797,21.955
                                   C488.991,364.469,457.665,339.934,422.804,332.819z M255.987,292.27c-20.012,0-36.253-16.232-36.253-36.27
                                   c0-20.03,16.241-36.262,36.253-36.262c20.038,0,36.27,16.232,36.27,36.262C292.257,276.038,276.025,292.27,255.987,292.27z" />
                                    </g>
                                </svg>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="direction_rtl">
                    <div class="b-1">
                        <div class="b-2">
                            <div class="content content2">
                                <svg class="cardpro-iconBack_Common cardpro-iconback5" fill="#000000" width="30px"
                                    height="30px" viewBox="0 0 24 24" version="1.2" baseProfile="tiny"
                                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                    <path
                                        d="M20.5 15.134l-2.457-.503 1.483-.396c.533-.143.85-.69.707-1.225-.142-.533-.689-.85-1.225-.707l-1.508.403c.037-.231.071-.464.071-.706s-.034-.476-.071-.707l1.51.404.26.034c.441 0 .846-.295.965-.741.143-.533-.174-1.082-.707-1.225l-1.483-.397 2.455-.502c.216-.044.42-.156.577-.333.386-.436.347-1.102-.089-1.488-.436-.386-1.102-.347-1.488.089l-1.663 1.874.398-1.479c.144-.533-.173-1.082-.706-1.226-.531-.142-1.082.173-1.226.706l-.407 1.517c-.366-.299-.771-.544-1.219-.717l1.102-1.102c.391-.391.391-1.023 0-1.414s-1.023-.391-1.414 0l-1.086 1.086.793-2.379c.069-.209.075-.441 0-.667-.184-.552-.781-.851-1.333-.666-.552.184-.85.78-.667 1.333l.793 2.379-1.086-1.086c-.391-.391-1.023-.391-1.414 0s-.391 1.023 0 1.414l1.102 1.102c-.447.173-.853.419-1.219.717l-.405-1.515c-.143-.534-.697-.852-1.224-.708-.534.143-.851.69-.708 1.224l.396 1.485-1.662-1.877c-.146-.164-.345-.285-.578-.333-.57-.117-1.127.25-1.244.82s.251 1.128.822 1.245l2.454.503-1.48.396c-.533.143-.85.691-.707 1.225.119.447.523.741.965.741l.26-.034 1.508-.404c-.039.231-.073.465-.073.706 0 .242.034.475.071.707l-1.508-.404c-.532-.142-1.081.173-1.225.707-.144.533.174 1.082.707 1.225l1.483.397-2.455.502c-.216.044-.42.156-.577.334-.387.436-.347 1.102.089 1.487.436.387 1.103.347 1.488-.089l1.665-1.878-.398 1.484c-.144.533.173 1.082.707 1.225l.26.034c.441 0 .845-.294.965-.741l.406-1.515c.366.298.771.544 1.22.716l-1.104 1.102c-.391.39-.391 1.023 0 1.414s1.023.391 1.414 0l.706-.707h.252l-.666 1.999c-.069.209-.075.441 0 .667.184.552.781.851 1.333.666.553-.184.851-.78.667-1.333l-.666-1.999h.252l.707.707c.196.195.451.293.707.293s.512-.098.707-.293c.391-.39.391-1.023 0-1.414l-1.102-1.103c.448-.172.854-.418 1.22-.717l.406 1.517c.12.447.523.741.965.741l.26-.034c.533-.143.851-.691.707-1.225l-.397-1.48 1.662 1.874c.146.165.345.285.577.333.57.117 1.128-.251 1.244-.821.117-.57-.251-1.127-.821-1.244zm-7.428-.634c-1.379 0-2.5-1.121-2.5-2.5s1.121-2.5 2.5-2.5 2.5 1.121 2.5 2.5-1.121 2.5-2.5 2.5z" />
                                </svg>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="direction_ltr">
                    <div class="c-1">
                        <div class="c-2">
                            <div class="content content3">
                                <svg class="cardpro-iconBack_Common cardpro-iconback3" fill="#000000" height="19px"
                                    width="19px" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                                    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 496 496"
                                    xml:space="preserve">
                                    <g>
                                        <g>
                                            <path
                                                d="M440,336c-5.552,0-10.6,1.968-14.672,5.144l-7.96-4.6L455.68,317.6l-7.096-14.344l-47.872,23.672l-17.984-10.384
                                       L421.04,297.6l-7.096-14.344l-47.872,23.672l-17.984-10.384L386.4,277.6l-7.096-14.344l-47.872,23.672L289.296,262.6l52.608-14.6
                                       l-52.608-14.608l42.136-24.328l47.872,23.672L386.4,218.4l-38.312-18.944l17.984-10.384l47.872,23.672l7.096-14.344
                                       l-38.312-18.944l17.984-10.384l47.872,23.672l7.096-14.344l-38.312-18.944l7.96-4.6C429.4,158.032,434.448,160,440,160
                                       c13.232,0,24-10.768,24-24s-10.768-24-24-24s-24,10.768-24,24c0,1.856,0.256,3.648,0.664,5.384l-7.296,4.208l2.752-42.648
                                       l-15.968-1.032l-3.432,53.296l-17.984,10.384l2.752-42.648l-15.968-1.032l-3.432,53.296l-17.984,10.384l2.752-42.648
                                       l-15.968-1.032l-3.432,53.296l-42.208,24.368l13.728-53.84L256,204.688V156.28l44.44-29.624l-8.872-13.312L256,137.056v-20.768
                                       l44.44-29.624l-8.872-13.312L256,97.056V76.288l44.44-29.624l-8.872-13.312L256,57.056V46.528c9.288-3.312,16-12.112,16-22.528
                                       c0-13.232-10.768-24-24-24s-24,10.768-24,24c0,10.416,6.712,19.216,16,22.528v10.528l-35.56-23.712l-8.872,13.312L240,76.28
                                       v20.768l-35.56-23.712l-8.872,13.312L240,116.28v20.768l-35.56-23.712l-8.872,13.312L240,156.28v48.408l-38.952-38.952
                                       l13.728,53.84l-42.208-24.368l-3.432-53.296l-15.968,1.032l2.752,42.648l-17.984-10.384l-3.432-53.296l-15.968,1.032l2.752,42.648
                                       l-17.984-10.384l-3.432-53.296l-15.968,1.032l2.752,42.648l-7.296-4.208C79.744,139.648,80,137.856,80,136
                                       c0-13.232-10.768-24-24-24s-24,10.768-24,24s10.768,24,24,24c5.552,0,10.6-1.968,14.672-5.144l7.96,4.6L40.32,178.4l7.096,14.344
                                       l47.872-23.672l17.984,10.384L74.96,198.4l7.096,14.344l47.872-23.672l17.984,10.384L109.6,218.4l7.096,14.344l47.872-23.672
                                       l42.136,24.328L154.096,248l52.608,14.608l-42.136,24.328l-47.872-23.672L109.6,277.6l38.312,18.944l-17.984,10.384
                                       l-47.872-23.672L74.96,297.6l38.312,18.944l-17.984,10.384l-47.872-23.672L40.32,317.6l38.312,18.944l-7.96,4.6
                                       C66.6,337.968,61.552,336,56,336c-13.232,0-24,10.768-24,24s10.768,24,24,24s24-10.768,24-24c0-1.856-0.256-3.648-0.664-5.384
                                       l7.288-4.208l-2.752,42.648l15.968,1.032l3.432-53.296l17.984-10.384l-2.752,42.648l15.968,1.032l3.432-53.296l17.984-10.384
                                       l-2.752,42.648l15.968,1.032l3.432-53.296l42.208-24.368l-13.728,53.84L240,291.312v48.408l-44.44,29.624l8.872,13.312
                                       L240,358.944v20.768l-44.44,29.624l8.872,13.312L240,398.944v20.768l-44.44,29.624l8.872,13.312L240,438.944v10.528
                                       c-9.288,3.312-16,12.112-16,22.528c0,13.232,10.768,24,24,24s24-10.768,24-24c0-10.416-6.712-19.216-16-22.528v-10.528
                                       l35.56,23.712l8.872-13.312L256,419.72v-20.768l35.56,23.712l8.872-13.312L256,379.72v-20.768l35.56,23.712l8.872-13.312
                                       L256,339.72v-48.408l38.952,38.952l-13.728-53.84l42.208,24.368l3.432,53.296l15.968-1.032l-2.752-42.648l17.984,10.384
                                       l3.432,53.296l15.968-1.032l-2.752-42.648l17.984,10.384l3.432,53.296l15.968-1.032l-2.752-42.648l7.296,4.208
                                       c-0.384,1.736-0.64,3.528-0.64,5.384c0,13.232,10.768,24,24,24s24-10.768,24-24S453.232,336,440,336z M440,128
                                       c4.416,0,8,3.592,8,8s-3.584,8-8,8c-4.416,0-8-3.592-8-8S435.584,128,440,128z M56,144c-4.416,0-8-3.592-8-8s3.584-8,8-8
                                       s8,3.592,8,8S60.416,144,56,144z M56,368c-4.416,0-8-3.592-8-8c0-4.408,3.584-8,8-8s8,3.592,8,8C64,364.408,60.416,368,56,368z
                                        M248,16c4.416,0,8,3.592,8,8s-3.584,8-8,8c-4.416,0-8-3.592-8-8S243.584,16,248,16z M248,480c-4.416,0-8-3.592-8-8
                                       c0-4.408,3.584-8,8-8s8,3.592,8,8C256,476.408,252.416,480,248,480z M259.096,254.384l5.952,23.344L248,260.688l-17.048,17.048
                                       l5.952-23.344l-23-6.392l23-6.384l-5.952-23.344L248,235.312l17.048-17.048l-5.952,23.344l23,6.392L259.096,254.384z M440,368
                                       c-4.416,0-8-3.592-8-8c0-4.408,3.584-8,8-8c4.416,0,8,3.592,8,8C448,364.408,444.416,368,440,368z" />
                                        </g>
                                    </g>
                                </svg>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>


            </div>

        </div>


    </section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to try a different approach, try using CSS to do the animations and tranformations, here it is a base example, only to explain the idea of CSS animations

CSS animations will always run faster than javascript, and you can perform animations in a easier and cleaner way

Even you can repeat the animation infinite and with javascript or different css clases generate stagger items and then is up to your imagination

Hope it helps

```js
const items = document.querySelectorAll(".item");

items.forEach(item => item.classList.add("animating"));

// uncomment this to stop the animation
// setTimeout(() => {
//     items.forEach(item => item.classList.remove("animating"));
// }, 3000);
```

```css
.item {
  position: absolute;
}

.item.item-a {
  margin-left: 100px;
}

.item.item-b {
  margin-left: 200px;
}

.item.item-c {
  margin-left: 300px;
}

.animating.item-a {
  animation: fall 3s linear infinite;
}

.animating.item-b {
  animation: fall-reverse 5s linear infinite;
}

.animating.item-c {
  animation: fall-reverse 4s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes fall {
  0% {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }

  50% {
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
  }
  
  100% {
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    transform: rotateY(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes fall-reverse {
  0% {
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }

  50% {
    top: 50%;
    right: 50%;
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
  }
  
  100% {
    top: 100%;
    right: 0;
    transform: rotateY(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="item item-a">A</div>
<div class="item item-b">B</div>
<div class="item item-c">C</div>
```

Comment: The idea is great. Just how do I do this code in an infinite loop?

Comment: I have updated the example to do that. Check out the iteration count of css animations https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-iteration-count and how to define an animation in CSS https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes

Comment: I mean by repeating loop, creating a loop with **jQuery** so that the elements are repeated infinitely.

Comment: Also, you can create randomness behaviour mixin that css classes with a little of javascript, but that would require a little more work. Good luck!

Comment: The example code has been updated with infinite css loop :D (those animations are generated with css, so the infinite loop is setted with css too)